# css transition height to hide content in container

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have a div absolute positioned located on the bottom side of the screen. I want to hide its content with an animation (not only setting display none) when a sibling div is clicked by transitioning max-height to 0.

The problem is that the content has at the same time child tags which keep height setted, causing to overflow the current body height.

What is the best solution to solve it?

I have reproduced the behaviour: https://codepen.io/javheroli/pen/QWbyZEr?editors=0110

```
.hide-container{
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 4em;
  transition: opacity .8s, max-height .5s;
}
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s, max-height .5s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to transition only the height property and add an `overflow: hidden` definition.

That way when you reduce the height the content just gets hidden. If you also want to animate the content you could animate the opacity of the child elements. It would be easier to check if you'd provided your HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by adding `overflow: hidden;` to your `.hide-container .hide` element.